# What else can you learn other than phrasal verb and idioms to sound like a native english speaker?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I have learnt a few phrasal verbs and idioms through a [site](http://www.fluentu.com/english/blog/english-phrasal-verbs/) that i found very helpful.

I was wondering if there's anything else like this to learn to improve my English (I don't know what PV and idioms are collectively called)

Advance apology if i made any mistake

Comment: Hello! It's not a big deal, but in fact, this question isn't a good fit for this site, because questions about resources for learning English are considered off-topic. If you have any other questions that are about specific issues you encounter while learning English, a good place to ask is the [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

Phrasal verbs are definitely a huge help. I've noticed there are a few other spots in a sentence where I know a writer doesn't have English as their first language when I see them. I worked as an English tutor in college and these days do a lot of ghost writing and proofreading for my employer who is a native Spanish speaker. These things come up constantly.

*A vs AN:*

Basics - singular don't forget to use yours a's and an's.

Advanced - it's actually the sound that matters, not the letter the word starts with.  "An honest" sounds like "an **o**nest" "A european" sounds "a **y**uropean"

*Singular/Plural*

Pay attention to the **number** of things one **is** talking about at all times.
For example, the noun the verb "is" belongs to here was "number", not "things" = singular = "is".

"You" always uses same verb word as "we and they".  All use **are**, **were**, and **have**, and never have an S at the end of other verbs (**swim**/swims, **hate**/hates). I is the same way, but for "I **am**" instead of "I **are**".

*Silent ED*

I've noticed that the letters ED are sometimes the first to go in a sentence, especially if it's harder to hear out loud. I've corrected the following a lot:

What happen was >> What happen**ed** was

After, we decide to >> After, we decide**d** to

We really tried. We even allow her >> We really tried. We even allow**ed** her

Note: I really try to avoid most formal language terms when explaining this. I found a lot of my students' eyes would glaze over when I did. If they didn't, I was preaching to the choir, so what was the point?